# How to select only matched sub-document of mongodb using python

Tags: python, mongodb

```
Document in Mongo ->

            {
             emp_id : 11
             proj_info : 
                    [{
                     proj_id : 91
                     proj_name : 'abc'
                     proj_team : 
                            [{
                               name : 'Ravi'
                               member_emp_id : '55'
                               designation : 'manager'
                            }
                            {
                               name : 'Ram'
                               member_emp_id : '66'
                               designation : 'consultant'
                            }]
                    }   
                    {
                     proj_id : 92
                     proj_name : 'pqr'
                     proj_team : 
                            [{
                               name : 'Sham'
                               member_emp_id : '15'
                               designation : 'manager'
                            }]
                    }   
                    {
                     proj_id : 93
                     proj_name : 'xyz'
                     proj_team : 
                            [{
                               name : 'Karan'
                               member_emp_id : '25'
                               designation : 'manager'
                            }]
                    }   
            }]
}
```

This is mongoClient query which is I written in Python -

```
     collectionObject.aggregate([{'$match':"proj_info.proj_team.member_emp_id":'55',"proj_info.proj_id":'91','emp_id':'11'}},
{'$unwind':"$proj_info"},
{'$match': {"proj_info.proj_team.member_emp_id":'55'}},
{'$unwind': "$proj_info.proj_team"},
{"$group": {"_id": "$_id","key": {"$first": "$key"},"proj_team": {"$push": "proj_info.proj_team"}}}]):
```

Example I want the output as only sub-document, whose inputs is  `emp_id:11`, `proj_id:91` and `member_emp_id:55`.

I want Expected output =>

```
proj_team : {
               name : 'Ravi'
               member_emp_id : '55'
               designation : 'manager'
            }
```

Please help me to solve.
=======================------===============

Comment: check your previous schema.

Comment: Thanks @Manohar Gavit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks but still I had to make some changes as it was not giving expected output, I made these changes =>

```
collectionObject.aggregate([
{'$match':{'emp_id': '11', "proj_info.pro_id": '11'   }},

{'$unwind': "$proj_info"},

{'$match': {"proj_info.proj_team.member_emp_id": '55' }},

{'$unwind': "$proj_info.proj_team"},

{'$project': {"proj_info.proj_team": 1,"_id" : 0}}

]):
```

and this worked for me.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

welcome to Stackoverflow, you can use [${project}](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) method to reduce it to the scope of the subdocument and then you can use `${match}` there, like this:

```
collectionObject.aggregate([
{'$match':"emp_id":'11'}},
{'$project': {"proj_info": 1}},
{'$match':"proj_id":'91'}},
{'$project': {"proj_team": 1}},
{'$match': {"member_emp_id":'55'}}])
```

Comment: collectionObject.aggregate([{'$match':{"project_info.project_stakeholder_info.holder_key": str(sqldt[0]),'emp_id': str(sqldt[11]), "project_info.project_id": str(sqldt[1])}},{'$unwind': "$project_info"},{'$match': {"project_info.project_stakeholder_info.holder_key": str(sqldt[0])}},{'$unwind': "$project_info.project_stakeholder_info"},{'$project': {"project_info.project_stakeholder_info": 1,"_id" : 0}},]):