# Access data in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, api, google-analytics

I'm trying to work with GG Analytics API and the response I get is not JSON but a kind of weird dictionary, I guess a nested dictionary, anyway, I've never encountered this kind of layout and I have no idea how to access rows in data. Let's say I want to access the first metric value in data (reports -> data -> rows -> metrics -> values = 33.361625), how should I proceed?
I've tried many things but I can't find the right formula.

Here is my body response:

```
{
    'reports': [{
        'columnHeader': {
            'dimensions': ['ga:campaign'],
            'metricHeader': {
                'metricHeaderEntries': [{
                    'name': 'ga:adsenseRevenue',
                    'type': 'CURRENCY'
                }, {
                    'name': 'ga:adsensePageImpressions',
                    'type': 'INTEGER'
                }, {
                    'name': 'ga:adsenseCTR',
                    'type': 'PERCENT'
                }, {
                    'name': 'ga:totalPublisherRevenuePer1000Sessions',
                    'type': 'CURRENCY'
                }]
            }
        },
        'data': {
            'rows': [{
                    'dimensions': ['(not set)'],
                    'metrics': [{
                        'values': ['33.361625', '1241', '24.25463336019339', '41.136405672009865']
                    }]
                },
                {
                    'dimensions': ['bath'],
                    'metrics': [{
                        'values': ['0.001371', '3', '0.0', '0.6855']
                    }]
                }, {
                    'dimensions': ['buffer'],
                    'metrics': [{
                        'values': ['0.0', '2', '0.0', '0.0']
                    }]
                }]
                }
            ],
            'totals': [{
                'values': ['5617.691293', '80215', '37.27108396185252', '120.7716068580028']
            }],
            'rowCount': 443,
            'minimums': [{
                'values': ['0.0', '0', '0.0', '0.0']
            }],
            'maximums': [{
                'values': ['933.667229', '12299', '162.5', '670.1915']
            }],
            'isDataGolden': True
        },
        'nextPageToken': '10'
    }]
}
```

Thank you,

Comment: This may help you,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54088312/how-to-select-only-matched-sub-document-of-mongodb-using-python/54125182#54125182

Comment: Some dumb things like body['reports']['data'], but I can't get over the first entry.

Comment: Try reports[0].data.rows[0].metrics[0].values[0]

Comment: How python is helping you here?

Comment: @yonBav Thank you. This worked body['reports'][0]['data']['rows'][0]['metrics'][0]['values'][0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error on your JSON/Dict on line 38, that line should not exist, anyway, to get the value your looking for try this:

>>> response['reports'][0]['data']['rows'][0]['metrics'][0]['values'][0]

'33.361625'

Comment: Yeah a copy-paste error. I got the same answer in the comments, Thank you.